# Problema com div que actualiza conteúdo

Tags: php, mysql

Bem pessoal eu tenho uma script ajax a fazer requisições a cada 1 segundo a minha base de dados para mostrar conteúdo novo que tenha sido publicado na base de dados porém estou a encontrar um problema esse conteúdo tem sempre um formulário por com uma `input box` para comentar e o meu problema está ai como esta sempre a fazer requisições a cada 1 segundo náo me deixa escrever o comentário como posso resolver isto ?

Script

```
<script>
            //LISTA POSTS ESTABELECIMENTOS
                $(document).ready(function() {
                $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); // This part addresses an IE bug.  without it, IE will only load the first number and will never refresh
                setInterval(function() {
                $('#mostra_posts').load('ajax/mostra_posts.php?id_estabelecimento=<?php echo $row->id; ?>');
                }, 1000); // the "3000" here refers to the time to refresh the div.  it is in milliseconds. 
                });
                // ]]>
            </script>

<?php
session_start();
require_once("../gtm/bd/funcoes.php");
ligarBd();  

$id_estabelecimento = $_REQUEST['id_estabelecimento'];

$result_post=mysql_query("select * from posts where estabelecimento_id='".$id_estabelecimento."' order by data desc");
while($row_posts=mysql_fetch_object($result_post)){
$result_user_anex=mysql_query("select * from users_social where id='".$row_posts->user_id."'");
$row_user_anex=mysql_fetch_object($result_user_anex);
?>

<section class="container" style="margin:15px 0px 0px 0px; border-top-left-radius: 2px; border-top-right-radius: 2px;">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">
           <div style="float:left; margin:0px 0px 10px 0px; "><img width="50" height="50" src="<?php echo $row_user_anex->user_foto ?>"/></div>
           <h3 style="float:left; margin:15px 0px 0px 10px;"><?php echo utf8_encode($row_user_anex->fb_nome); ?></h3>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>      
<p><?php echo utf8_encode($row_posts->opiniao); ?></p>
<script>
  FB.init({ appId: '1404139796547995', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true, oauth: true });

  function post_fb<?php echo $row_posts->id_post; ?>() {  
    FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.authResponse) {
        FB.ui({
            method: 'feed', 
             message     : "Vê este comentário sobre <?php echo $row_cat->titulo; ?> no @SabeOnde",
             link        : '<?php echo $row->link_site; ?>',
             picture     : 'http://sabeonde.pt/gtm/anexos/capa/<?php echo $row_capa->id_anexo; ?>.<?php echo $row_capa->tipo ?>',
             name        : '<?php echo $row_cat->titulo; ?> | SabeOnde',
             from: '<?php echo $_SESSION['FBID'] ?>',
             description : '<?php echo $row_posts->opiniao; ?>'                      
        },
        function(response) {
          if (response && response.post_id) {
            alert('Comentário Partilhado com sucesso!');
          } else {
            alert('Falha ao partilhar o comentário');
          }
        });
      } else {
        alert('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
      }
    }, {scope: 'publish_actions, publish_stream'});
    return false;
}
</script>  
<div style="float:left; margin:0px 5px 10px 0px;"><a href="#">Gosto</a></div>
<div style="float:left; margin:0px 5px 10px 0px;"><a href="#" >Comentar</a></div>
<div style="float:left; margin:0px 5px 10px 0px;"><a href="#" onClick="post_fb<?php echo $row_posts->id_post; ?>()">Partilhar</a></div>
</section>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Não seria melhor colocar esse formulário *fora* dessa área que atualiza constantemente?

Comment: Sim mas vai me ficar fora do while que me apresenta os posts

Comment: Coloca seu código pra facilitar a visualização do seu problema.

Comment: já esta ai agora coloquei a caixa dos comentários fora mas como fica fora do while só apresenta no ultimo post

Comment: Tudo isso fica dentro da div de id `mostra_posts`, certo?

Comment: Não o script fica noutro ficheiro que e onde tem a div que mostra os posts

Comment: Sim esse conteúdo fica todo dentro dessa div

Comment: No fundo eu queria que a parte dos comentarios fica-se fora do while mas que fosse apresentada em todos os posts isso já resolvia o meu problema mas nao sei como posso fazer visto que fora do while só me apresenta no ultimo post

Comment: Podem dar ai uma ajudinha

Comment: Podem dar uma ajuda